# Is there any container as std::vector in Metal Shader Language?

Tags: metal

MSL supports templates, but there is not c++'s stl. Looks like it does not have an analogue of std::vector and there is not any generics containers or may be I miss?

Comment: Correct.  No shading language supports such a container.  You will need to pass in a fixed-sized buffer and something to tell the shader how many items are occupied.

Comment: Thanks, but how someones makes physics engines on GPU? I mean it could be complicated algorithms, and on shaders all what we have is C's 'for in' loops?

Comment: There is no ready solution because you can't really allocate GPU memory from the GPU itself so you need CPU code to allocate it for you. What you can do is pass a big chunk of memory that's already allocated and do whatever you want with it.